# Finding $a$ in modular arithmetic while $a<0$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm having a problem understanding this equation in modular arithmetic I have tried searching the internet but I haven't found a solution, I hope you can help.

$a = k(26) + b\; \text{ for }a > 0\:$ 
(26 is just what he uses in the book as he is explaining the Caesar cipher)

The author then goes on to say that even if $a$ were negative, we could easily find a positive number $b$ in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,26\}$ such that $a$ is congruent to $b$ by dividing the positive number $-a$ by $26$, obtaining:

$-a = q(26) + r = (q+1)26 - (26-r),\quad            
q\ge 0, \enspace 0\le r<26$.

My question is: How did he get to that equation, I seem to have tried anything, it might be that I am really tired, but I have to know the answer before I sleep.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Which equation exactly?

Comment: Caser cipher actually; $c = p + 3 \pmod{26}$ where $p$ is plaintext character, $c$ is the ciphertext character.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand how we got to the last 2 equations -a = q(26) + r=(q+1)26 - (26-r)

Comment: he is not really using the 3 letter shift only, he is showing substitutions with any letter in the alphabet

Comment: Then the book is not a good book by calling it Caesar cipher. What is $k(26)$ and $q(26)$?

Comment: This chapter is called modular arithmetic the caesar cipher was used in the first chapter

Comment: I'm just giving context for the question

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: Elementary Cryptanalysis: A Mathematical Approach by Abraham Sinkov

Comment: http://index-of.es/Varios-2/Elementary%20Cryptanalysis%20A%20Mathemathical%20Approach.pdf  Link to the pdf version

Comment: I hope it is clear, now

Comment: The notation $q$ and $r$ are usually used in the quotient/remainder of the division algorithm.  Given and $n \ge 0$ there are integers $q\ge 0$ and $r: 0 \le r < 26$ so that $n = 26q + r$.  So if $a < 0$ then there are $q,r$ so that $-a = 26q + r$.  This cipher seems to rely on finding $k$ and $b > 0$ so that $a = 26k + b$.  This is obviously doable if $a > 0$ but if $a < 0$.  Well, it's still doable. As $-a=26q +r$ then $a = 26(-q-1) +(26-r)$ and let $k=-q-1$ and let $b = 26-r$ which is positive.

Comment: "My question is: How did he get to that equation"  $-a$ is a positive number.  He just divided $-a$ by $26$ and took the remainder.  If $-a = 26q + r$ then $a = 26(-q) -r$.  The remainder $r$ is between $0$ and $25$ so $-r$ is between $-25$ and $0$.  If we add  and subtract $26$ to that we get $a = 26(-q-1)+ (26-r)$ and $26-r$ is between $1$ and $25$.  Which is good.

Answer (score 1):

All he is saying is that if $a < 0$ is it possible to say

$a = 26k + b$ where $b = \{1,....., 26\}$.

He does:

$a < 0$ so $-a > 0$.  Then if you divide $-a$ by $26$ you we get a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$ so that

$\frac {-a}{26} = q + \frac r{26}$ and

$-a = 26q + r$ and $ 0 \le r < 26$.

Then $-a = 26(q+1) -26 + r = 26(q+1) - (26-r)$.  So $0 \le r < 26$ we have $0 < 26-r \le 26$ so if we let $b = 26-r \in \{1,..., 26\}$ and let $k = -q-1$ we get

$a = 26(-q-1) +(26-r) = 26k + b$.

It works.

If $a > 0$ then there is a $b \in \{1....26\}$ where $a \equiv b \pmod {26}$.

And if $a < 0$ then there is a $b \in \{1... 26\}$ where $a \equiv b\pmod {26}$.

And if $a = 0$ then $a \equiv 26\pmod{26}$.

....

It's not deep.

I'd have done it simply by saying.  "Just add or subtract $26$ until you get some between $1$ and $26$ inclusive".

====== old answer===

If $a > 0$ there is a $k$ and a $b > 0$ so that $a = 26k + b$. [The book seems to have established that.]

But what if $a < 0$.  Can we find a $k$ and $b > 0$ so that $a = 26k +b$.

Yes.

If $a < 0$ then $-a > 0$ and we can find $q$ and $r: 0 \le r < 26$ so that

$-a = 26q + r$

$= 26(q+1) - 26 + r$

$= 26(q+1) - (26-r)$ and note that $r < 26$ so $ 26 -r > 0$.

But then

$a = 26(-q-1) + (26-r)$.

Let $k = -q-1$ and $b = 26-r$ and this works fine

$a = 26k + b$ where $b > 0$ even though $a < 0$.

[ I suppose for $a = 0$ the book uses $0 = 26(-1) + 26$? ]

[It's not entirely clear what the book is trying to show.]

Comment: I feel like he complicated it a tad bit more than it should be because saying add and substract 26 until you get some between 1 and 26 inclusive is much clearer

Comment: Well, to be fair, I haven't actually proven that you if add and subtract 26 several times that you will be *able* to end up in a spot that is between $1$ and $26$.  Maybe you will have $k < 0$ but $k+26 > 26$  Or $j > 26$ but $j-26 < 0$.  And it isn't clear that if you have $a < -5654796857$ that if we just keep adding $26$ will find $a = 26*M + b$ where $b=1...26$ *must* happen.  You can prove it with induction but... this is an introductory course.

Comment: ...or you have $k < 0$ but $k + 26$ ... is also less than zero... and $k + 26 + 26$  ... is *still* less than $0$.  How do I know I'll have to get to a positive number eventually.  And what if I get so bored that I blink and my attention wanders and suddenly I've gone *way* past positive and no am way bigger than $26$... how do I know I can get down.

Comment: You intrigued me, when I learn induction, I'll try it, do you have any good resources, I'm still in school so not really exposed to all that

Answer (score 0):

We usually write

$$a = k(26) + b\; \text{ for }a > 0\:$$ as
$$a = 26 \cdot k + b\; \text{ for }a > 0\:$$  where $k$ is the quotient when divided by 26 and $b$ is the remainder.

Now look at

$$-a = q(26) + r = (q+1)26 - (26-r),\quad            
q\ge 0, \enspace 0\le r<26.$$

it is used to find the representative of a negative $-a$ number

$$-a = 26\cdot q + r = 26 (q+1) - (26-r),\quad            
q\ge 0, \enspace 0\le r<26.$$

The trick is, add and subtract 26. Take the $\mod 26$ in the last equation. And, the shortest way is $26-a$ if $a < 26$.

Comment: Thanks a lot m8

Comment: But may I ask, why did he say divide by 26, this kinda threw me off

Comment: It assumes, $a$ can be bigger than $26$.

Comment: The thing is he's interested in the *remainder* not the quotient.  You divide by $26$ to find the remainder. And you adjust it by adding or subtracting $26$ to get a value $b$ between $1$ and $26$.

Comment: @fleablood that is what I said. Let me clear if not.

Comment: I was responding to "why did he say divide by 26".  The answer is... to get the remainder.

Comment: @fleablood ah ok. yes.